# Firebase send token code when app is opened everytime

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send token code when app is opened. I don't want to send new token, only same token. This code work fine but only for first time.

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    registerToken(token);
    Log.d("TOKEN", token);
}

private void registerToken(String token){
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("token", token)
        .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("url")
        .post(body)
        .build();
try {
    client.newCall(request).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}}
```

I know `onTokenRefresh` only start when app installed. How can I send token to server when I open my app first time, second time, 3. 4. etc.

I tryed to add this code to my activity but app not run. give me an error

> Unfortunately (app name) has stopped.

I have added this code to main activity in onCreate

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
registerToken(token);
```

and after this code

```
private void registerToken(String token){
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("token", token)
        .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("url")
        .post(body)
        .build();
try {
    client.newCall(request).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}}
```

Sory for my bad English.

Edit: my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

my FirebaseInstanceIDService.java

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        registerToken(token);
        Log.d("TOKEN", token);
    }
    private void registerToken(String token){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("Token", token)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("url")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 2:
I think this code not work in mainactivity.java

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("url")
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
```

my app crashed when I add this code to mainactivity.

Full code is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        registerToken(token);
        Log.d("TOKEN", token);
    }
    private void registerToken(String token){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("token", token)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("url")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I send data with AsyncTask?

Comment: Please add stack trace for better debugging

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You can get the token at any moment by calling:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

So you can put this in your `MainActivity.onCreate()` and send it.

```
public void onCreate(Context ctx) {
    ...
    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    if (token != null) {
        registerToken(token);
    }
    ...
}
private void registerToken(String token){
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("token", token)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("url")
            .post(body)
            .build();
    try {
        client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}}
```

When you first start the application, the token won't have been generated yet by the time the activity starts. For that reason you need to check for `null` *and* also implement `onTokenRefresh` in the service.

Comment: Hi Frank, I have updated my post. I tryed your code but not work. screenshot from mainactivity with your code http://image.prntscr.com/image/a128f7639ce04bb5b0ea3e1dd52eeabe.png

Comment: I think this should be the preferred way to actually get it in activity. Thanks for pointing it out to me. I certainly missed it for some reason while answering. Will edit my answer aswell.

Comment: I tryed your code, first time app is opened but second time crashed Unfortunately (app name) has stopped.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can you help me? I can send you my files with github project. Can you look at it? I have been trying this for weeks but not work

Comment: If the app crashed, there is a stack trace. Add the stack trace to your question and indicate in the code which line number caused the crash.

Comment: Hi Frank I tryed your code again and its like in photo. First time work but later not work. my photo is here. That's true or ? 
http://image.prntscr.com/image/faeba0c1e90f442f9af187a90bdbf145.png
http://image.prntscr.com/image/b61f89d959fc435092cdd467fc02ed00.png

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to **make a custom method in your FirebaseInstaceIdService** like this:

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = FirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static String fcmToken;


    public static String getToken() {

        fcmToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        Log.d(TAG, "Old token: " + fcmToken);

    return fcmToken;
    }
```

}

Now in your **onCreate** of **mainActivity** *call that method and retrieve the token on every app lauch like this:*

```
FirebaseInstanceIdService.getToken();
```

*Do let me know if this gives you an idea to achieve what you want to do.*

Comment: The method looks good. But why would you put this in the service? Wouldn't it just as well fit into the activity itself?

Comment: Hello Nishant, thank you for help. I didn't add this code. It's give me errors. I have updated my post with mainactivity and FirebaseInstanceIDService

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString("token", token);
        edit.commit();


    }
}
```

now you can get the token inside your MainActivity onCreate method send to server

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
  String   token = sharedpreferences.getString("token", "");
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("Token", token)
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("url")
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            try {
                client.newCall(request).execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

now everytime when token get changed via firebase it will automatically changed in shared preference too

Comment: Hello Umar, thank you for help. That's not work. I have updated my post with activitymain.java and FirebaseInstanceIDService.java

Comment: I have added my mainactivity and FirebaseInstanceIDService. I will add your code with screenshot in a few minute.

Comment: I just suggested you the code to retrieve and store device token but I not included the network call, which you need to implement

Comment: I added your code, first time genereted token but second time nothing in logcat. http://image.prntscr.com/image/8e32e8d82fff4d74bf7fcf06ee8516d5.png
http://image.prntscr.com/image/1ae6c340e02a4cf69df68eebdae4e97c.png

Comment: You got it wrong. Just implement ontokenrefresh method already in your code of question and call my method send Registrationttoserver inside of it

Comment: Can you share your full code on my mainactivity and FirebaseInstanceIDService. I got an error. Private method 'sendRegistrationToServer(java.lan.string)' is never used. I'm new on android maybe I can't make it well.

Comment: Keep ontokenrefresh and sendregistrationtoken inside firebaseidservice class ok then call the last to lines from my answer inside mainactivity and make networkconnection and pass token

Comment: I can send you my files with github project. Can you look at it? I have been trying this for weeks but not work.

Comment: Sir, the app crashed if I use  Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("url")
                .post(body)
                .build();
in mainactivity. there is github link. https://github.com/serkancay/FCM-Test

Comment: I am not found any code inside main activity in the github link you provided  and what exactly error you are getting at requestbuilder

Comment: error Unfortunately (app name) has stopped.
Can you download and try your code on that project?

Comment: wower.esy.es/register.php have you any email? I cand send you user id for phpmyadmin